Scheduled auto-run an add-in using Design Automation API
Is it possible to update a Revit Cloud Model on schedule (for example, every day after 5 PM) through Design Automation API and Power Automate?
I understand that for 2022 and later versions, a cloud model can be accessed, and an add-in can be run to update a model using Design Automation API. However, could we run this on a schedule with Power Automate without the user having to manually trigger the app? Would 3-legged authentication allow this?

Have you tried it?

In theory it should all work.
You could create a Custom Connector in Power Automate that uses 3-legged authentication, since 3-legged tokens are allowed by the POST /workitems endpoint.
Here is info on how you could then interact with the Revit Cloud Model from the work item:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/revit_specific/revit-cloud-model-integration/

It works, but every time the app runs automatically on schedule (with Power Automate), I need to click on allow
for the authorization pop-up window. That means I can't run it overnight when no one is behind the computer to allow the authorization. Is there a way to have it run without the authorization popup window every single time?


How can an Authorize window pop up when the flow is running on schedule, without anything having to be open in the browser? 2) Did you set the Refresh URL correctly on the "Security" tab of your Custom Connector? PA should refresh the token automatically using that, which requires no user interaction

